# how to select table name from the table itself in a dynamic way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to select table name from the table itself

for example

```
Select * ,(TableName) from Table1

union

Select *,(TableName) from Table2
```

i don't want to do it in a static way

```
Select * ,'TableName' as tbl from Table1

union

Select *,'TableName'  as tbl from Table2
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

There is no metadata function like `SELECT OBJECT_NAME(this)` you can use.

The `FROM Table1` bit is static so what's the problem anyway?

Comment: actually i have 7 tables like 30_table1 , 40_table1, 50_table1 , ever number means a company name i need to identify the company name inside the query so i need the table name to know the company

Comment: @kingofoceans - But you have to know the name of the table to query it in the first place.

Comment: i may do it in a static way but i thought it might be a solution in dynamic

Comment: @kingofoceans - No there isn't. At least in 2005 (I can think of a horrible way of accomplishing this in 2008 which I won't mention in case someone somewhere actually uses it)

Comment: @kingofoceans - If you have to query only 7 tables, then you are far better off doing it "the static way" as you said it, than trying to come up with a dynamic query

Comment: The database design you're describing sounds horrible. A separate table for each company?

Comment: @shesek Actually I'm stuck with legacy systems. what if i told you that the table has 728 column

Comment: Damn :-\  My only suggestion is... quit?

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be dynamic but it's a lot more complex than your first code block up there.

Declare a varchar variable large enough to hold your select script (eg. @script).
Declare a cursor for iterating through your tables in sysobjects table. It's something like:

```
declare cc cursor for select name from sysobjects 
where type='U' and name like '%yourTableNamePatternHere%'
order by name
```

Go through the records in a while loop using fetch next and @@fetch_status, assemble your big union-query into @script and finally use sp_executesql to have @script executed by the server.

That's it.
Here is the script in one listing:

```
declare @n varchar(100), @script nvarchar(2000)
set @script = ''

declare cc cursor for select name from sysobjects where type='u' and name like '%yourTableNamePatternHere%'
open cc
fetch next from cc into @n

while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
    if @script <> '' set @script = @script + ' union '
    set @script = @script + 'select <column1>, <column2>, ''' + @n + ''' as tableName from ' + @n 
    fetch next from cc into @n
    end

close cc
deallocate cc

-- print @script
exec sp_executesql @script
```